# elementwise operation on array of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, elementwise-operations

I am new to Julia and I am trying to migrate from existing code in Mathematica. I am trying to do: with an array of vectors, subtract a constant vector from it. Here is what I want:

```
a=[[1, 2], [1, 3]]

println(a)

b=a.-[1,1]

println(b)
```

I want `b=[[0,1],[0,2]]` but it gives me error about dimension mismatch. I am a bit at a loss regarding the difference between "a list of vectors" and "a matrix" in Julia. I am not sure what is the right way to do these two different things.

I then tried broadcasting but it did not work either

```
a=([1, 2], [1, 3])

println(a)

b=broadcast(-,[1,1],a)

println(b)
```

Finally, I tried

```
a=([1, 2], [1, 3])

println(a)

b=a.-([1,1],)

println(b)
```

and it worked.

My questions:
Why don't the first two work?
Is this a hack walkaround or should I be using this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Ref` to avoid vectorization on the second argument of your difference:

```
julia> a .- Ref([1,1])
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 1]
 [0, 2]
```

Without that you were iterating over elements of `a` as well as elements of `[1, 1]` which ended in calculating an unvectorized difference between a vector and a scalar so it did not work.

Comment: Or wrap it in a tuple. Or array. Though that last one is slower.

Comment: With wrapping on tuple or array it would work as long as he uses `+` and `-` which are defined for vectors. However, when he decides to multiply or divide - it would not work as those are not defined for vectors. (@DNF you of course know it but this is a comment for other people reading this and this is an important difference compared to how numpy works)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

```
julia> broadcast(.-, a, [1, 1])
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 1]
 [0, 2]
```

In more recent Julia versions, "dotted operators" can be used as stand-alone values of a wrapper type:

```
julia> .-
Base.Broadcast.BroadcastFunction(-)
```

which you can then broadcast.